# Why do I get this diagonal? (normal of a curve at specific point)

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

I had to code how to draw the normal of a curve at a specific point; $t_0 = \frac{2\pi}{5}$ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723461/how-to-plot-the-normal-at-a-point-for-a-given-parametric-curve)

The curve is given by the parametric equations:

$$x(t) = sin(3t)$$

$$y(t) = sin(4t)$$

Where $t[0, 2\pi]$. For this type of parametric curve, the parameter equations for the normal line are given by the following equations:

$$x_{tg} = f(t_0) + f'(t_0)(t-t_0)$$
$$y_{tg} = g(t_0) + f'(t_0)(t-t_0)$$

The problem is that I do not understand why I get the following diagonal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06dzA.png)

Could you please explain it with details?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't those the equations for the *tangent* line rather than the normal?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth the exercise says normal but I think they meant tangent yes. Then let's talk about the tangent at a specific point

Comment: What did you expect to get instead? The slope of your line is $y'(t_0)/x'(t_0) \approx -0.5$.